# Removing rows based on whether or not there is a 1-1 correspondence in observations

Tags: r, dplyr

In dplyr, I need to eliminate all rows who's ID's (see below) correspond more than once with more than one different period number.  In the example below, Id's 1002 and 1003 should be removed, since they exist in more than one period, but I need both observations for 1001 to remain, as well as the 1004 observation.

```
ID    Period  Other
1001  01      AAx56
1001  01      77YTQ 
1002  01      GG897
1003  01      LLOQ1
1004  01      QQw34
1002  02      AZZZ2
1002  02      XXXXr
1003  02      22RRR
```

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(Period)==1)`

Comment: @akrun this appears to have worked.  Thanks!  What exactly is n_distinct doing?  Can this be extended if I wanted to know which ID's only appear in two periods, etc?

Comment: @Josh.D  It is a wrapper for `length(unique(Period))` i.e. the number of unique Period. If you want to extend for 2 periods, just change the condition to `==2`